# Prove whether or not the function is a bijection

Tags: functions

Problem statement:

Let  $ f: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$  be defined as $ f(m, n) = (3m + 7n, 2m + 5n) $. Is $f$ a bijection, i.e., one- to-one and onto? If yes then give a formal proof, based on the definitions of one-to-one and onto, and derive a formula for $ f^-1 $. If not then explain why not.

---

My work:

( I don't know how I came to this reasoning. So bear with me)

$m = 3m + 7 n$

$n = 2m + 5n$

1) multiply  $n$ by 1.5 to eliminate the $m$ variable giving me $ n = .5 $

2) repeat step 1 but multiply this time by $1.4$ to eliminate $n$

I'm stuck afterwards... I don't even know what I really just showed, that it is one - to - one?

Comment: You can't multiply by 1.5 as 1.5 doesn't exist here. ;) You're working with integers.

Comment: so i could use lcm? Even then, i think i'd be stuck. let's say I do                          $2(m = 3m + 7n) $                                                                                                            /////   $- 3(n= 2m + 5n) $                                                                                          /////  $ (2m,-3n = -n) $  which doesn't see mto make sense to me :/   sorry for the slash, comments are so hard to format on here

Comment: I get  $ m = 5a - 7b $ and  $ n = 3b - 2a $ . I guess because those aren't the same they aren't onto. Anybody can quickly explain why is that? I mean is it because m and n are always within the integer set?

Comment: No to prove something is onto, you have to show that $\forall d \in D \ \exists c \in C \ s.t \ f(c) = d$.
The pair $(a, b)$ was arbitrary. So evaluate $f(5a - 7b, 3b - 2a)$ and see what you get.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand too well what you just did. How would I evaluate a function that I don't have?  Could I use maybe proof by contradiction or that wouldn't work for a function?

Comment: Isn't your function $f(m, n) = (3m + 7n, 2m+ 5n)$?

Comment: Yeah, totally agree, I can plug in my a and b for one specific arbitrary point, but to evaluate it seems kinda hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is onto since for any given $(a,b)\in \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ we have $$f(-7b+5a,3b-2a)=(a,b)$$
To see why the function is one-to-one, assume that $f(m_1 ,n_1)=f(m_2,n_2)$ then 
$$3(m_1-m_2)=7(n_2-n_1)$$ and $$2(m_1 -m_2)=5(n_2-n_1)$$ multiplying both side of these two equation by $5$ and $7$ respectively we get $$15(m_1-m_2)=14(m_1-m_2)$$
so $m_1-m_2=0$ and hence $n_1-n_2=0$. That is $(m_1,n_1)=(m_2,n_2)$ by the definition f is one-to-one.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to find an inverse to see that it is a bijection.

Suppose $f(m, n) = (x, y)$. Then $3m+7n=x, 2m+5n=y$. Now this is just a linear equation over $\mathbb{Z}$, with determinant $3\times 5 - 7\times 2=1$, so $x, y$ will be a linear combination of $m, n$ with integer coefficients, which is in the domain.

Now you have an inverse, the function is a bijection.

Comment: Hey I see how you got to the determinant, but would one have to multiply and re-arrange the matrix ( how I'm seeing it in my head) to then find the so-said inverse?

Comment: @Marc-AndreLeclair You don't need to, if you want to then just use the [matrix inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_2.C3.972_matrices).